# Проблема с кодом для создания "каши" из русских слов и фамилий

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код функции для Telegram-бота,  который должен создавать текст-"кашу" из рандомных русских слов и фамилий.
Вот отрывок кода с этой функцией:

```
def fish(message):
        mes = message.text.split()
        if len(mes) >= 2:
            temp = mes[1]
            for i in '.,?/\\':
                if i in temp:
                    temp.replace(i, '')
            mes = int(temp)
            if not isinstance(mes, int):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи команду с длиной текста (количеством слов).\nНапример: /fish 32')
            else:
                first_reply = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian.txt')
                second_reply = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danakt/russian-words/master/russian_surnames.txt')
                russian_words = first_reply.content.decode('cp1251')
                russian_surnames = second_reply.content.decode('cp1251')
                list_words = russian_words.splitlines()
                list_surnames = russian_surnames.splitlines()
                list_all = list_words.extend(list_surnames)
                mesg_text = ''
                for i in range(mes):
                    temp_int = random.randint(0, len(list_all))
                    mesg_text = mesg_text + ' ' + list_all[temp_int]
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mesg_text)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи команду с длиной текста (количеством слов).\nНапример: /fish 32')
```

Но почему-то на строке `temp_int = random.randint(0, len(list_all))` возникает ошибка `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. Не могу понять, почему объект типа `NoneType`, если по сути должен быть `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> list_all = list_words.extend(list_surnames)
> ```

https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.extend/

> Дополняет список элементами из указанного объекта.
>
> ```
> list.extend(it) -> None
> ```

Вероятно, надо было написать

```
list_all = list_words + list_surnames
```